# How to get the QuickTime OCX control to register correctly and work in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, com, quicktime, ocx

Initially the QuickTime OCX seemed to briefly work. In visual Studio I did the following:

- Added the `QuickTime Plugin Control` to the toolbox by right-clicking in the tools pane -> choose toolbox items -> COM Components -> check QuickTime Plugin Control, ok.
- Dragged the control from the toolbox to my empty Form.

It showed a panel with the QuickTime Logo. Then I went to code view and explored some properties and methods via intellisense (I want to automate some AAC encoding with it).

After switching back to the designer view, Visual Studio crashed, and since then I cannot get anything to work any more. I have removed all references from the solution and restarted Visual Studio. Tried to remove and add the control to the toolbox again (that part works) but as soon as I try to drag it to my form I get the following error:

```
Failed to create component 'AxHost'.  The error message follows:
 'System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to initialize component.
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.DepersistControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.ActivateAxControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.TransitionUpTo(Int32 state)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection.Add(Control value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ControlCollection.Add(Control value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Design.ParentControlDesigner.AddChildControl(Control newChild)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Design.ParentControlDesigner.AddControl(Control newChild, IDictionary defaultValues)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner.InitializeNewComponent(IDictionary defaultValues)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Design.AxHostDesigner.InitializeNewComponent(IDictionary defaultValues)'
```

I also tried a repair of QuickTime via `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features` -> Repair, to no avail.

Then I tried re registering the DLL:

```
regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTPlugin.ocx"
```

Result:

```
DllRegisterServer in C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTPlugin.ocx succeeded.
```

Retried using it, but no luck, then tried this:

```
regsvr32 /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTPlugin.ocx"
```

Result:

```
The module "C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTPlugin.ocx" was loaded but the entry-point DllInstall was not found.
Make sure that "C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTPlugin.ocx" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again.
```

Not sure where to go from here. It worked briefly, then it broke, how to fix?

Comment: Can you play QT files outside of VS? How did you install QT initially?

Comment: @Papa, playing and encoding all works outside of my solution, I've had QT installed for a few years now, always updated, never had problems before I started trying the OCX. In fact the control is still working perfectly in FireFox right now (just tested).

Comment: You tried starting a new VS project? I've had some funky things happen in VS where I just had to restart from scatch.

Comment: @Papa Yes, tried in a new project with the same results. However I did register QTOControl.dll successfully and could drag the "Apple QuickTime Control 2.0" to my form without any problem (which is not the same one used earlier). As soon as I try to do something with it in runtime, it now throws this exception: Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.QTOLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Found a solution to that last problem [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/108809/Error-loading-QuickTime-Control-with-Net). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the original QuickTime OCX issue, I found InvalidOperationException from System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.DepersistControl() occurred because the ActiveX control is lack of IPersistStreamInit, IPersistStream or IPersistStorage interface. AxHost requires one of these, so make sure to include one of these on creating your ATL ActiveX control.

This is an answer for people having troubles on adding the custom ATL ActiveX controls into WinForms, like me. Look for MSDN for more details about IPersist interfaces.